# What's wrong with the following two lines

Tags: python

I am trying to write a piece of python code which will write a piece of CMake code ...

But when I get to the following phase:

```
def_desc = "blaa"
s = "    FILE(WRITE ${CONFIG_H} \"/* {0} */\\n\")\n".format(def_desc)
```

then python yells at me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ferencd/tmp/blaa.py", line 2, in <module>
    s = "    FILE(WRITE ${CONFIG_H} \"/* {0} */\\n\")\n".format(def_desc)
KeyError: 'CONFIG_H'
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
```

I understood that somehow the interpreter thinks that `{CONFIG_H}` is supposed to mean a parameter from the parameter list of `format` ... but no, I'd really like to print out that into the output ... as it is.

How can I deal with this situation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to escape brackets "}" if it uses not for format variable.

```
def_desc = "blaa"
s = "    FILE(WRITE ${{CONFIG_H}} \"/* {0} */\\n\")\n".format(def_desc)
```

Comment: Yess, thank you. Today I learned that \ is not a good way to escape { in python :)

Answer (score 5):

you need to use double braces:

```
s = "    FILE(WRITE ${{CONFIG_H}} \"/* {0} */\\n\")\n".format(def_desc)
```

It is much easier, though, to use template library for stuff like this, like jinja or mako.

Comment: It's easier to use a template library than `format` with a single parameter? I doubt it. Template libraries would have the same issue with escaping special characters.

Comment: @interjay it is easier to write cmake files (which OP mentioned is trying to do) with template library than assembling it line by line ;-)

Comment: @m.wasowski I have just started learning python ... :) But thanks for mentioning the template libraries, I will research them out  shortly!